# Entrada nula via teclado em um recebimento de variável via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if, while, else

<s>Boa Noite! Em minhas experiências práticas no JavaScript, eu tentei criar uma condição para alertar o usuário sobre uma variável que ele deixou passar despercebido ao apertar a tecla **enter** duas vezes. Porém, ao tentar solucionar este problema, eu realizei duas tentativas:</s>

```js
/*Tentativa 1:*/

var linha = Array(3,3);
var x, y;
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
    if (linha[x,y] == null) {
      alert("Digite alguma coisa");
      while (linha[x,y] == null){
        linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
        if (linha[x,y] == null) {
          alert("Digite alguma coisa");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
/*Tentativa 2:*/

var linha = Array(3,3);
var x, y;
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
    if (linha[x,y] == " ") {
      alert("Digite alguma coisa");
      while (linha[x,y] == " "){
        linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
        if (linha[x,y] == " ") {
          alert("Digite alguma coisa");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Pergunta:** Qual método é mais viável para solucionar este problema acima?

Comment: Coloca esse problema um pouco de lado e remove os trechos de código que inseriu tentando resolver isso. Faça o resto funcionar antes. Você pode achar que está funcionando, mas não está. Rode esse código num debugger ou REPL e inspecione os valores das variáveis. Sua array está sendo inicializada incorretamente e `linha[x,y]` não faz o que você pensa.

Comment: Mas @bfavaretto, neste caso eu estou montando uma matriz com o Array(). Se eu for colocar a proposta de projeto relacionado a este algoritmo que eu estou montando aqui no fórum, os moderadores irão anular o post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao converter null, ou uma string vazia, com `parseInt`, o valor atribuído será *NaN* (*Not-a-Number*). Portanto, a maneira, possívelmente, mais segura de testar se o usuário não digitou valor nenhum, é usando a função global `isNaN`. Ela retorna `true` se o valor testado não é um número (*isNot-a-Number*). Então, ficaria:

```
var linha = Array(3,3); 
var x, y; 
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) { 
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) { 
        linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna")); 
        if (isNaN(linha[x,y])) { 
            alert("Digite alguma coisa");
            while (isNaN(linha[x,y])){ 
                linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna")); 
                if (isNaN(linha[x,y])) { 
                    alert("Digite alguma coisa"); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

De acordo com o que você disponibilizou, acho que isso pode resolver o problema.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Gratidão! Agora o algoritmo não deixará que o usuário o encerre sem digitar os valores que a lógica pede. Valeu!! ;-)